# DBI Frida Stalker is not tracing instructions

Tags: reverse-engineering, dbi, instrumentation, frida

Let me start by saying that I'm new to Frida, so I might be doing a noobish mistake.

I'm trying to "stalk" a simple `while` loop and print the instructions using a transformer.
My `target.c` file looks like below

```
// target.c
#include <stdio.h>

void read_n_print(int mul)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d * %d = %d\n", n, mul, n * mul);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        read_n_print(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling the code with `gcc`: `gcc target.c -o target-demo1`

Now, I'm trying to use the Stalker API to trace the code defined in `target.c` while excluding .so libraries.

My `agent.js` is below

```
// agent.js
'use strict';

var modules = Process.enumerateModules();

modules.forEach(module => {
    console.log(module.name, module.base, module.size);
});

modules.forEach(module => {
    if ((module.name.indexOf("target-demo1") === -1) &&
        (module.name.indexOf("libmylib.so") === -1)) {

        console.log(`Excluding ${module.name}`);

        // We're only interested in stalking our code
        Stalker.exclude({
            "base": module.base,
            "size": module.size
        });
    }
});

Process.enumerateThreadsSync().map(t => {
    console.log(`Thread id is ${t.id}`);

    Stalker.follow(t.id, {
        transform(iterator) {
            console.log("HERE")
            var instruction = iterator.next()
            do {
                console.log(instruction);
                iterator.keep()
            } while ((instruction = iterator.next()) !== null)
        }
    });
});
```

I'm loading my script with `frida target-demo1 -l agent.js`

When I first input a number in the running `target-demo1` process, frida prints a stream of instructions.
After this, regardles of how many numbers I enter into the `target-demo1`, frida doesn't print anything.

I was expecting the stalker transform to run as long as frida is attached to `target-demo1` and to keep printing
instructions as the while loop executes.
Have I understood something wrong?

I'm running

- frida version `15.1.8` (installed with `python pip`)
- inside `Linux LAPTOP-7SIL4P0D 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`

As a side note, if I remove the `Stalker.exclude()` code, the `target-demo1` process segfaults.
The process doesn't segfault if I'm using frida `14.2.18` (`pip install frida-tools==9.0.0`).

Answer (score 0):

transform will only run once for each block of code. you need to use onReceive callback to receive execution trace of code.

see example in the doc. https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api